# require is not defined javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente problema, trato de llamar una dependencia de esta forma pero me dice que no esta definido la palabra require, quisiera saber si solo de puede usar sobre el servidor express o sobre cualquier servidor que se utilice sobre node.

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando:

Netbeans 8.0
Windows 10

Comment: estas tratando de correr node.js en un navegador?! node es para el lado del servidor, no el navegador.

Comment: Bueno veo que ese es el problema, de igual manera, como se realiza, usando express??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para acceder a la API de Twitter, no intentes utilizarla desde el navegador directamente por medio de *browserfy* o similares, pues deberías exponer tus claves, que son secretas. Esta [desaconsejado por ellos](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries#javascript).

Crea una aplicación servidor que consulte la API y expone en un punto de acceso para "hacer un puente" en tu servidor que haga realmente la consulta, de forma que tus claves no estén comprometidas.

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var twclient = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '', // debes poner los datos correctos en estos campos
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token_key: '',
  access_token_secret: ''
});

// creamos la applicacion con express
var app = express();

// configuramos la carpeta 'public' como una carpeta de contenido estatico, html, css, etc.
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/ultimotweet/:user', function(req, res){

  // preparamos los datos del usuario a consultar
  var usuario = {
    // en screen_name, pones el nombre de usuario sin la arroba.
    // req.params.user, el valor que viene en la solicitud ej: /ultimotweet/nombreuser => nombreuser
    screen_name: req.params.user,
    // la cantidad de mensajes a obtener
    count: 1,
    // solo mensajes propios (no re-tweets)
    include_rts: false
  };

  twclient.get('statuses/user_timeline', usuario, function(error, tweets, response){
    if(error) throw error; // se produjo un error, manejar aquí

    if (tweets.length) {
      // como hay tweets, con res.send enviamos la respuesta al navedador.
      res.send(tweets[0].text);
    } else {
      // como no hay tweets mandamos un mensaje que lo explique.
      res.send('El usuario no ha twiteado aun!');
    }
  });

});

app.listen(3000);
```

Luego haz una aplicación cliente similar a esta:

Utilizando ajax, consultas el punto de acceso creado en la aplicación anterior y obtienes la información que estas buscando.

```
<input id="user" type="text" placeholder="ingresa el usario de sin la @">
<button id="pedir">Obtener</button>
<div id="destino_tweet">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#pedir').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/ultimotweet/' + $('#user').val()
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $('#destino_tweet').text(data);
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Deje un repositorio en GitHub para que puedas probar este concepto, con las instrucciones para que puedas ejecutarlo.

https://github.com/rnrneverdies/nodetwitter

Answer (score 1):

El método `require();` solo se usa en node.js del lado de servidor para que funcione en el navegador del lado del cliente usa una librería como requiere.js o browserfy

Comment: aunque no esta mal la respuesta, y como es parte de la pregunta, hay que aclarar que Twitter desaconseja utilizar las api directamente desde el cliente. https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries#javascript ya que deberías exponer las claves de tu aplicación. Tal vez una mejor respuesta seria explicar como utilizar node como puente hacia twitter.

Comment: Es verdant pero la raspiest a es habilitar require en el navegador

Comment: Pues que tal usar azure o heroku, ya que solo es llamar tweets?

Comment: Creo que la respuesta es correcta. La persona pregunta por que `require()` no le funciona y la respuesta es la que da @jose-santacruz-lopez. El que twitter deba llamarse desde el servidor o el cliente es irrelevante a la pregunta. Aclararle a la persona que pregunta que el que este corriendo un servidor con javascript no significa que pueda emplear en el navegador funciones que solo estan definidas en el servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Si esta en el lado del cliente no uses `require()` sino has link del modulo en tu archivo html con `<script src='./twitter'></script>`

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, más bien es un comentario, si no tienes los puntos para comentar simplemente deja que otra persona lo haga para mantener el orden del sitio y la comunidad no te de puntos negativos .Saludos.